# How to share variables among shell scripts in a sequence of commands?

Tags: shell

Suppose I have a lot scripts: 1.sh,2.sh 3.sh, ..., n.sh, and I want to use them this way:

```
./1.sh | 2.sh | 3.sh | ... | n.sh
```

I'd like to share variables from 1.sh to the others.

I tried to export the variables. The problem is: I don't want them to exist after the last completes. It would be easy to make n.sh to erase them, but it sounds a workaround to me.

There are a lot of answers with solutions here on Stack Overflow, but neither of them goes round to me.

All in all, I'm asking if there is a way of constructing variables that work only for a sequence of commands with pipes.

Is there a way of doing this without workarounds?

Comment: There is a way: use command grouping, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
( MYVAR=42; export MYVAR ; ./1.sh | 2.sh | 3.sh | ... | n.sh )
```

The shell creates a first subshell to execute scripts in the `( ... )`

`MYVAR` is then only defined inside the subshell, and it is visible to all scripts. Its lifetime is the same as the first subshell.

Anychange to `MYVAR` during execution of one of the `1.sh`... `n.sh` script is not visible outside: in other words, if `1.sh` modifies the value of `MYVAR`, then `2.sh` and other scripts are only seeing the oringinal value (42 in the example).

Answer (score 0):

Put it all into `( ./1.sh | 2.sh | 3.sh | ... | n.sh )` parenthes and set all variables to your taste after the opening `(` - ( ) is a subshell and thus after the end, nothing from the environment is left - no need to "remove" anything.